# SystemD : Package systemd-sysv is not available, but is referred to by another package

Tags: linux, ubuntu, service, installation, systemd

I am trying to install and configure systemD on lindux debian but I get errors when installing systemd-sysv which I understood was necessary to get systemD to manage services.

When I run

```
apt-get install systemd-sysv
```

I get :

```
# apt-get install systemd-sysv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package systemd-sysv is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'systemd-sysv' has no installation candidate
```

Does someone know how to overcome this ? How can I have a running version of systemD on my system?

Comment: which version of *Debian* are you running?

Comment: my version number is 14.04

Comment: so why have you tagged this question as `debian` when you are using `ubuntu`?

Comment: and btw, since this question is really not related to *programming*, you might (in the future) ask such questions on [su] or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*ubuntu* started shipping `systemd` with *Utopic Unicorn* (where it is in the *universe* repository) and fully includes it since (the currently upcoming) *Vivid Vervet*.

Therefore, if you want to install `systemd` on your ubuntu-system (via the package manager), you need to first upgrade your entire system to a version that actually supports it.